# How to return value from a function launched inside a switch statement?

Tags: javascript

I have the following switch statement. All the cases work including the 'custom' case. the only challenge is that I am unable to return the radval from the 'custom' case.  It shows the right value if I do it in the console log.  I have tried several options mentioned in the comment below but none works.

```
    document.body.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            let target = e.target;
            let responsible;
            let radval = 0.5;;
            let yourshare;
            switch (target.id) {
            case '100':
                    radval = 100/100;
                    break;
            case '50':
                    radval = 50/100;
                    break;
            case '25':
                    radval = 25/100;
                    break;
            case '75':
                    radval = 55/100;
                    break;

            case '33':
                    radval = 33/100;
                    break;
            case '0':
                    radval = 0;
                    break;
            case 'custom': 
                    document.getElementById('customsplit').onchange = function () {
                            let custval = document.getElementById("customsplit");
                            radval = custval.value / 100;
                            return(radval);  
// Also tried return radval and tried a function outside the switch statement that was called here.  But no success.
                    }
                   break;

    }
```

Comment: Returning a number from a change listener doesn't make any sense - return values inside handlers only check to see if `false` is returned (for bubbling/delegation)

Comment: Ok, I am new to JS and I went through quite a bit blogs and articles but couldn't find anything.  In this case the custom is a non-radio number input so that a user can enter some random number such as 22 instead of a radio button.  I'm not sure how would I go from here.  Thus the question.

Comment: The value inside the function isn't generated until much later, when the user changes the element, by which time the function that assigned the event handler is long since finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way of solving this problem.

The in-code comments should make clear how everything works.

```js
// Lets us select some DOM elements
const
  container = document.getElementById("container-div"),
  customInput = document.getElementById("customsplit"),
  checkedRadioSelector = 'input[name="radios"]:checked';

// Stores our value, which will be changed by `setGlobalVal()`
let globalVal;

// Calls `update` whenever one of the inputs changes
container.addEventListener("change", update);


// Defines the listener
function update(ev){

  // Gets the active radio button, its value, and the custom value
  let
    activeRadio = document.querySelector(checkedRadioSelector),
    radioVal = activeRadio?.value, // 'optional chaining' in case no active radio
    customVal = customInput.value;

  // `customVal` IF radio = 'custom' AND customVal converts to int
  if(radioVal == "custom" && (customVal = parseInt(customVal)) >= 0){
    setGlobalVal(customVal/100);
  }
      
  // `radioVal` IF a radio changed AND radioVal converts to int
  else if (ev.target.name == "radios" && (radioVal = parseInt(radioVal)) >= 0){
    setGlobalVal(radioVal/100);
  }
  else{ /* Does nothing if neither set of conditions is met */ }
}

// Defines the setter
function setGlobalVal(newValue){
  globalVal = newValue;
  console.log(`new value set: ${globalVal}`);
}
```

```css
label{ margin-right: 1em; }
#custom-fields{ margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="container-div">
    <label><input type="radio" name="radios" value="100" />100</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radios" value="75" />75</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radios" value="50" />50</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radios" value="33" />33</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radios" value="25" />25</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radios" value="0" />0</label>
    <div id="custom-fields">
        <label><input type="radio" name="radios" value="custom" />custom:</label>
        <label><input type="number" id="customsplit" min="0" max="100"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```